# Calculating the latitude and longitude of two circumscribed lines of two circles and four intersection points in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geometry

I would like to know the latitude and longitude of two circumscribed lines of two circles and four points in the Google Maps API.

The radii of the center coordinates of the two circles are the same, and the radii of the two circles are the same.

The picture below is a simple image displayed in the Google Maps API.

[image]

This picture marked what I wanted to know
[image]

While searching, I looked at various concepts such as trigonometric functions, Pythagorean theorem, radian, etc. I tried it alone, but it was difficult, so I asked for help. please

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes?hl=ko#maps_polyline_simple-javascript

If you click jsfiddle at this Google Maps api address and insert this code, the image sample above will appear.

```
//test js code
const citymap = {
    chicago: {
        center: { lat: 33.8, lng: 130.6 },
    },
    newyork: {
      center: { lat: 35.7, lng: 133 },
    }
};

function initMap() {
  // Create the map.
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: { lat: 33.09, lng: 130.712 },
    mapTypeId: "terrain",
  });

// Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
// Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
for (const city in citymap) {
  // Add the circle for this city to the map.
  const cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map,
    center: citymap[city].center,
    radius: 130000,
  });
}

var cirCle1center= google.maps.LatLng(33.8, 130.6)
var cirCle2center= google.maps.LatLng(35.7, 133)

var cirCle1X1 = 33.8;
var cirCle1Y1 = 130.6;
var cirCle2X1 = 35.7;
var cirCle2Y1 = 133;


var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: [
    { lat: cirCle1X1, lng: cirCle1Y1 },
    { lat: cirCle2X1, lng: cirCle2Y1 }],
   strokeWeight: 2,
   strokeColor: '#FFAE00',
   strokeOpacity: 0.8,
   strokeStyle: 'dashed',
   map: map
  });
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

I tried to find the angle with two coordinates, but I don't know how to find the circumscribed line of the two circles and the latitude and longitude of the four intersections.

Comment: The [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) has all what you need. Sounds fairly easy to calculate heading from circle 1 center point to circle 2 center point, then compute the points with -90 and +90 degrees, distance from center point would be the circle radius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Geometry` library provided by Google provides the means to calculate a heading (direction) and from that calculate the location of a point using the `offset` ~ essentially as pointed out by @MrUpsidown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google Maps: Circles</title>
        <style>
            #map{
                width:800px;
                height:600px;
                float:none;
                margin:auto;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
        
            class marker{
                constructor( map, latlng, args={}){
                    this.map=map;
                    this.latlng=latlng;
                    this.args=args;
                    return this.create();
                };
                create(){
                    let options=Object.assign({
                        clickable:true,
                        draggable:false,
                        position:this.latlng,
                        map:this.map
                    },this.args );
                    
                    return new google.maps.Marker( options );
                };
            };

            
            function initMap() {
                const radius=130000;
                const div=document.getElementById('map');
                
                const citymap = {
                    chicago: {
                        center: { lat: 33.8, lng: 130.6 },
                    },
                    newyork: {
                        center: { lat: 35.7, lng: 133 },
                    }
                };
                
                const map = new google.maps.Map( div, {
                    zoom: 6,
                    center: { 
                        lat: 33.09, 
                        lng: 130.712 
                    },
                    mapTypeId: "roadmap"
                });
                
                // store references to plotted circles and calculated points
                let circles={};
                let points={};
                
                const keys=Object.keys( citymap );  // these are newyork & chicago
                const oSpherical=google.maps.geometry.spherical;    // the Google Geometry library to help calculate heading & offset
                
                
                // helper function to take start/end points
                // and radius to determine the tangents to the circle
                const locatetangents=(start,end,radius)=>{
                    let heading=oSpherical.computeHeading(
                        start.getCenter(),
                        end.getCenter()
                    );
                    return [
                        oSpherical.computeOffset(
                            start.getCenter(),
                            radius,
                            heading+90
                        ),
                        oSpherical.computeOffset(
                            start.getCenter(),
                            radius,
                            heading-90
                        )
                    ];
                };
                
                // utility to add markers
                const addmarkers=( city, arr )=>arr.forEach( ( point, i )=>new marker( map, point, { title:`${city}-${i}` } ) );
                
                
                // plot two circles...
                for( const city in citymap ) {
                    circles[ city ]=new google.maps.Circle({
                        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                        strokeOpacity: 0.2,
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        fillColor: "#FF0000",
                        fillOpacity:0.1,
                        map:map,
                        center:citymap[ city ].center,
                        radius:radius
                    });
                }
                
                
                let start=circles[ keys[0] ];
                let end=circles[ keys[1] ];             
                
                // origin
                points[ keys[0] ]=locatetangents( start, end, radius );
                addmarkers( keys[0], points[ keys[0] ] );
                
                //endpoint ( swap start/end )
                points[ keys[1] ]=locatetangents( end, start, radius );
                addmarkers( keys[1], points[ keys[1] ] );
                
                
                // do whatever you need to with 4 deduced points
                Object.keys( points ).forEach(city=>{
                    let a=points[city];
                    console.log(
                        'City: %s - points[ lat:%s, lng:%s ],[ lat:%s, lng:%s ]',
                        city, a[0].lat(), a[0].lng(), a[1].lat(), a[1].lng()
                    )
                });
                
                
                
                // connect circle centres...why?
                new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: [
                        circles[ keys[0] ].getCenter(),
                        circles[ keys[1] ].getCenter()
                    ],
                    strokeWeight:2,
                    strokeColor:'blue',
                    strokeOpacity:1,
                    map:map
                });
                
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBq...............&callback=initMap&libraries=geometry'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Rendered output]

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks for the detailed answer Professor. have a good day!

Comment: Glad it helped. One thing to note - with the above code ( all of the above ) the polylines are not being rendered as `geodesic` so as the radius of the circles change the observed lines will not necessaarily appear to connect to the correct locations whereas using `geodesic` polylines will yield peculiar looking lines as they follow the Earth's curvature. This effect is observable if you connect the 2 points on each circle (ie:diameter) and look at the intersection between diameters and line connecting both circles

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet. I haven't touched/optimized your code. Only added the geometry library and the related calculations at the end.

Basically, take your circle 1 and 2 center points. Calculate the heading between the 2, substract 90 degrees angle and compute offset with your circle radius distance to find the position of point 1 on circle 1. Do the same for point 2, but add 90 degrees instead. Repeat for second circle points. Draw the polylines between the points if you need to.

```js
const citymap = {
  chicago: {
    center: {
      lat: 33.8,
      lng: 130.6
    },
  },
  newyork: {
    center: {
      lat: 31.7,
      lng: 133
    },
  }
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the map.
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 33.09,
      lng: 130.712
    },
    mapTypeId: "terrain",
  });

  // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
  // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
  for (const city in citymap) {
    // Add the circle for this city to the map.
    const cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: "#FF0000",
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: 130000,
    });
  }

  var cirCle1center = new google.maps.LatLng(33.8, 130.6)
  var cirCle2center = new google.maps.LatLng(31.7, 133)

  var cirCle1X1 = 33.8;
  var cirCle1Y1 = 130.6;
  var cirCle2X1 = 31.7;
  var cirCle2Y1 = 133;


  var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [{
        lat: cirCle1X1,
        lng: cirCle1Y1
      },
      {
        lat: cirCle2X1,
        lng: cirCle2Y1
      }
    ],
    strokeWeight: 2,
    strokeColor: '#FFAE00',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeStyle: 'dashed',
    map: map
  });

  const heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(cirCle1center, cirCle2center);

  console.log(heading)

  // Point 1, Circle 1
  let p1c1Heading = (heading % 360) - 90;

  let p1c1 = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(cirCle1center, 130000, p1c1Heading)

  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: p1c1,
    map: map
  });

  // Point 2, Circle 1
  let p2c1Heading = (heading % 360) + 90;

  let p2c1 = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(cirCle1center, 130000, p2c1Heading)

  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: p2c1,
    map: map
  });
  
  // Point 1, Circle 2
  // Reuse previously calculated heading

  let p1c2 = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(cirCle2center, 130000, p1c1Heading)

  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: p1c2,
    map: map
  });

  // Point 2, Circle 2
  // Reuse previously calculated heading

  let p2c2 = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(cirCle2center, 130000, p2c1Heading)

  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: p2c2,
    map: map
  });
  
  // Polylines
  new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [p1c1, p1c2],
    strokeWeight: 2,
    strokeColor: '#FFFF00',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    map: map
  });
  
  new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [p2c1, p2c2],
    strokeWeight: 2,
    strokeColor: '#FFFF00',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    map: map
  });
}

window.initialize = initialize;
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Credits for this code example: @MrUpsidown https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238965/mrupsidown -->
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=geometry&callback=initialize"></script>
```